# Console.WriteLine is not a part of my "using System;" (System.Console does not exist)

Tags: c#, console, system, program-entry-point

New to c#, not new to programming. Actually working on my for project in c# and I have been wanting to write to the console. Everywhere I have looked, System.Console.WriteLine has been the unanimous choice. Here is what I have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace First_Project
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Henlo");//These two lines throw the error
        System.Console.WriteLine("Henlo");
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
        var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
        Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Henlo, Woo-urld!");
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
}
}
```

It is saying "The name Console does not exist in the current context" and "The namespace Console does not exist in the namespace System" respectively. I am hoping that I am just making a simple mistake but I cannot seem to figure it out on my own. If I have neglected to include any needed information, please let me know.

Comment: What exact project template did you use to create the project?

Comment: Um, I believe I used something like Windows Universal and then Selected Blank App @KirkWoll

Comment: @KirkWoll Thank you! I don't know how I didn't come across that. That is almost exactly what I searched in Google. My mistake.

Comment: Ha, no worries, glad i could point you in a helpful direction.